# Generating PDF between 2 sites

Tags: php, cakephp, pdf, cross-domain

I'm standing infront of a crossroad full of potential ways to solve my problem. My problem is that I want to refer specific users to a unique page that renders relevant PDF file for them. Preferably, I want to refer them to one site, which the relevant MySQL-data and plugin for pdf rendering isn't on. Hopefully, you can shed some light to which solution I should use.

**Reference**

- **Site A** - The site I prefer to refer them to be on
- **Site B** - The site containing the MySQL data and PDF plugin

**Info**

- Both sites are built through CakePHP 1.3
- Site A currently doesn't have a database attached to it. It simply runs on API calls only to Site B.
- These PDFs won't be that heavy to generate, though it would be interesting to find a solution which also accounts for this
- The reference to these PDFs occurs upon events, and are not sent to thousands of users at the same time.

## Solution #1

Refer them to Site B and generate everything there.

**Pros:** Easy to fix.
**Cons:** I don't want these users to know of Site B. Site B is intended mostly for internal communication, and would be best let out of this for given users.
**Thoughs:** Rather avoid this one.

## Solution #2

Have a page on Site A that [cURLs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) a page equal to Solution #1, and then outputs the same result.

**Pros:** Pretty much equal easy to fix.
**Cons:** Can't think of any.
**Thoughs:** Will the browser understand that I output a PDF? Or do I (if possible) copy headers reply from cURL request and set them in own `header()` before output?

## Solution #3

Generate the PDF once in Site B and place it on Site A. Then simply refer to the .pdf link.

**Pros:** Faster loading. Not that it matters in this case and might even go unnoticed.
**Cons:** Can't as easily modify the PDF output.
**Thoughs:** How would I transfer the file? The 2 sites are on the same server, so it would be possible with a simply path change, however all other communication between the sites are made to that they don't need to share servers. Shame to break that design. Maybe I would have to do an advanced cURL request and send the pdf file as a POST from Site B to Site A and upload it? Doesn't seem as neat solution either, though.

## Solution #4

Run an API from Site A to Site B to get relevant data based on ID from url. But also have the PDF plugin on Site A aswell.

**Pros:** In one way, quite a logical approach.
**Cons:** I would prefer to have all PDF generating on Site B only. Makes it easier to manage all of them.
**Thoughs:** I'm a bit unsure how much (if any) more beneficial this approach would be compared to Solution 2.

Many thanks for your time. Please motivate one of given solutions, or present your own one.

**EDIT:** Although code samples always are appreciated, I'm more interrested in the resoning and logic to why which one of the solutions, or an other, should be used. I already know how to solve most of these solution through coding. For visitors, feel free to link to relevant functions and methods regarding your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to hide Site B from the public eye.

The easiest way is to create a reverse proxy between Site A and Site B. 
You can do something like sitea.com/pdf-items/ will serve siteb.com/

EDIT:

The reverse proxy can be cross domain, the servers do not have to share anything in common, except for Site B being accessible by Site A (which sounds like it is already)

Apache has a simple approach using mod_proxy (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)

A quick google pulls up a guide for setting it up on Apache. http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies

Nginx has one too
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/using-nginx-as-reverse-proxy.html

IIS is a bit more complicated and I've never set it up, but the ability does exist according to the documentation.

EDIT 2: Approaching

Here we don't have to worry about PHP component. What happens is that the Apache server will map forward the request based on the proxy specified e.g. if Proxy is set Sitea.com/pdf siteb.com/ then sitea.com/pdf/alpha.pdf will actually request siteb.com/alpha.pdf . In this schema it will ignore the sitea.com PHP routing all together, but will honor siteb.com routing as it is a full-fledged request but done by sitea's webserver.

In regards to honoring, the requests for siteb, it implies that sitea.com/pdf/getpdf.php?id=1 will actually go through all motions as going to sitea.com/getpdf.php?id=1.

Alternatively if you want to setup a VHOST on siteA.com such as pdf.sitea.com you can setup the proxy that pdf.sitea.com maps to siteb.com, but this would be useless if both sitea and siteb are publicly accessible.

The reverse proxy works best if sitea.com is available to your audience and siteB is behind a firewall that has restricted access, so the proxy will let sitea.com visit a section of siteb.com that otherwise would not be accessible.

Files that would be modified are siteA.com Apache configuration for the host by enabling the proxy_mod and setting up the ProxyPass and ProxyReversePass under the VHOST or Server configuration.

Comment: Does this approach require the 2 sites to share servers? My first though would be to run this through VirtualHost, but that would enforce the need of these 2 to share servers.

Comment: By the looks of it, this solution seems to be more fitting for me. I suppose it's a better approach than simply "ripping" of generated pdf through a cURL? However, I still haven't grasped Apache at a whole. Could you supply an example of what files I should modify if I want pdf.site-a.com to load site-b.com, or even site-b.com/pdf/pdf_generators if cakePHP can handle the uri?

Comment: Updated the description in the answer

Comment: I ended up using virtual hosts and rewriterule. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can always create a "hidden" or atleast unknown page on site B that generates the PDF and outputs it directly (without a download dialog). Then on site A you could just implode the link to site B to download the content from site B, and show it to the user.

A user wont know that site B exists, but it will be slower because there is more data traffic between the two servers.

On site B hiddenfile.php:

```
<?
$p = new PDFlib();
if ($p->begin_document("", "") == 0) {
    die("Error: " . $p->get_errmsg());
}
$p->set_info("Creator", "Hugo Delsing");
$p->set_info("Author", "Hugo Delsing");
$p->set_info("Title", 'Hi');

$p->begin_page_ext($docWidth, $docHeight, "");

$p->end_page_ext("");
$p->end_document("");

$buf = $p->get_buffer();

$len = strlen($buf);
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Length: $len");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=hello.pdf");
print $buf;
exit;
?>
```

and on site A downloadFile.php

```
<?
$content = implode('', file('siteb/hiddenfile.php?user=1'));
$len = strlen($content );
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Length: $len");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
print $content;
exit;
?>
```

So I guess i would use solution B in a different way, to keep the seperate server option. Why? All solutions are good, but this once has no cons for you. So I guess you answered your own question.

Comment: This solution seems to be quite equal to my given Solution #2. My current pdf plugin generates it in some way that makes the browser able to show it on spot if possible, else download it. It would be nice to keep that feature, but I'm unsure what headers the plugin sends. Maybe it's the one you supplied in example?

Comment: Indeed your solution 2. You dont need an exact replica of the headers. If you set the content type to PDF, thats what the browser expects. Adding the content-disposition will make it possible for on the spot or download popup. A content length header is useful so the broswer knowns when its done downloading and can show a download meter.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. From all the different solutions i assume you are quite flexible in what you can do.

Personally i would use site B as a job queue server with the db on it (though the db would also be better on a different server). Ask for the users email address and once the job (processing the PDF) has been completed they get it emailed to them, or you could do what i suggested in the comments and send them to a page saying "generating pdf, will refresh in 10 seconds" which keeps refreshing until it finds the generated PDF. This would also allow it to scale pretty well (just add more workers) and would not hold up users while the PDF is being generated.

You can use Gearman to interface with PHP to create the job queue.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php

**Pros**

- Scales very well - just add more workers if you need more PDF's to be generated at once
- Uses are not held up thinking the page has crashed while the PDF is generated
- Not limited to just PDF's, you can queue any CPU intensive jobs in it
- Won't need to be ripped out and replaced with something different as site traffic increases (just add more workers)
- Allows control of how many processes / threads are trying to generate PDF's (apache for example will allow say 10 or more PDF's to be generated at once - you have little control over it when done directly in the web requests process and would be a way for attackers to crash your site)

**Cons**

- Requires installation and setup of gearman
- Requires you to create the gearman PHP scripts to actually generate the PDF

The main reason i would go down this route is because of the user experience, ease of scalability and control over the worker processes.

**Side Note**

Your setup of site A and B seems a little strange though i'm sure you have your reasons. If you have two servers, you would be better with nginx on site A proxying all requests to the internal server B with Apache, DB and gearman on it. You can then seperate the apps to seperate servers as your site grows in traffic.

Comment: The setup of the sites is something I was left with, and not my personal preference. So basicly, you say I should send the PDFs as attachments to their mail? Although that would be a nice approach and something I could do easily with through CodeIgniter, I'm not sure I can easily create PDF files and attach them in the same script execution in CakePHP 1.3. I may want to be able to inactivate these PDFs aswell. (I know people can Save them, but few will)

Comment: You don't have to send as emails. You could just send them to a page that says "created your PDF, page will auto refresh in 10 seconds" and stop refreshing once the PDF is generated. Emailing was just a suggestion - gearman is only a job queue, it's up to you how you get the PDF to the user once the job has completed ;)